# Symfony 3 jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: forms, symfony, jquery-ui, exception

I'm trying to understand forms in Symfony and I have to realize the field DateType.

My layout:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <input name="{{ form.date.vars.full_name }}" id="js-datepicker" value="{{ form.date.vars.value }}" type="text" placeholder="Например: 12/11/2018 " class="form-control input-lg m-b">
    <div class="form-errors text-danger">
        {{ form_errors(form.date) }}
    </div>
</div>
   <script>
    $( function() {
         $( "#js-datepicker" ).datepicker({
             format: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
         });
    });
</script>
```

My controller

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($client)
        ->add('date', DateType::class)
        ->getForm();
```

My Entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime $date
 */
 protected $date;
```

And I have a trouble. When I tried to run it I have this error.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").
```

But I cannot understand where my mistake. Help me, please! Thank you!

**UPDATE**:
I redecorate my twig code:

```
{% for formInput in form %}
    {{ form_label(formInput) }}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {{ form_widget(formInput) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-errors text-danger">
        {{ form_errors(formInput) }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And my controller:

```
    $formLabelAttr = 'col-sm-2 control-label';
    $formInputAttr = 'col-sm-10 form-control input-lg m-b';

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($client)
        ->add('fullName', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'Имя',
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => $formLabelAttr,
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Например: Иванов Иван Иванович',
                'class' => $formInputAttr,
            ],
        ])
        ->add('date', DateType::class, [
            'label' => 'Дата проведения',
            'label_attr' => [
                'class' => $formLabelAttr,
            ],
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Например: 12/12/2020',
                'class' => $formInputAttr,
            ],
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        ])
        ->add('diplomaNumber', HiddenType::class, ['data' => random_int(1, 200)])
        ->getForm();
```

Now, I have two problems:
1. I can observe the form__token label in the page (label) at the bottom of the form.
2. I can't submit form because I have the error in DateType field (Value is not valid).
What's wrong?

Comment: First I'd like to advice you to change field rendering to symfony way - {{ form_widget(form.date, {'attr': {'class': 'bla-bla-class'}}) }} and assign all additional attributes you need to render. And look at options widget and format in your type class - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a date filter.

{{ xxx_your_date_field|date("m/d/Y") }}

more details [twig date](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html#date)

also in your formType use single_text. more details [Rendering a single HTML5 Textbox](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#rendering-a-single-html5-textbox)

Comment: Thank you! But, I have this error now ---->
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (form[date]) at position 0 (f): The timezone could not be found in the database").

Comment: `<input name="{{ form.date.vars.full_name | date("m/d/Y") }}" id="js-datepicker" value="{{ form.date.vars.value | date("m/d/Y") }}" type="text" placeholder="Например: 12/11/2018 " class="form-control input-lg m-b">`

Comment: you are using createFormBuilder, so you don't need this input manually
in twig file. read here https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

Comment: Hi! I updated my code (and Update the ticket above). Could you help me, please?

Comment: you don't need to loop in form

Comment: I want to have div with a class after title and before input. And it's the reason why I used loop